# Fixing Blender Norman Rig

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm trying to fix Norman Blender Rig (https://www.blendswap.com/blend/7749)
because it's an excellent rig for animation training.
Would any of you have a faster solution than redo every facial driver by hand ?
[image: drivers broken]

Comment: Hi. For those unfamiliar with the issues with this rig, can you explain in detail what you are having to do by hand that you are hoping to do faster?

Comment: all facial drivers are broken, so I wondered if there was a python command or something to fix this, instead of re-creatinf all drivers...